# Parameters of a dirichlet distribution and posterior mode

Tags: dirichlet-distribution

What is the range in which the dirichlet parameters (alphas) should lie? I saw  the condition that alphas must be greater than 0. Then can I have alpha values between 0 and 1?

Comment: The [Wikipedia summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution) is explicit: the criterion is only $\alpha_i\gt 0$.  Greater than zero means exactly that; it doesn't also mean less than 1!  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_distribution#/media/File:Dirichlet-3d-panel.png for illustrations of the density for some $\alpha_i$ that exceed $1$.

Comment: Do you meant that alpha values 0.386 and 0.4935 and 1.266 are wrong? I estimated it by method of moments   and the equation derived in a reference of 1992. Can you please suggest me a method to estimate alphas  of a dirichlet distribution with equations. I will try again  to get parameter values. I am basically not from a statistical ground and new to especially  dirichlet distributions and Bayesian analysis.

Comment: Are any of those values zero or negative?  No, so they are consistent with the condition $\alpha_i\gt 0$.

Comment: Value of each variable lies between 0 and 1. I have three set of observations for each variable. For var1- (0.2, 0.75 and 0.82). For var 2 - (0.2, 0.22 and 0.12). For var3 - (0.6, 0.03 and 0.06). Each set of observations sums to 1. For var 1, I estimated the alpha as 1.266 by the method of moments given by "A. Narayanan,1992, A note on parameter estimation in the multivariate beta distribution".Then I found dirichlet mode for var 1. But I get negative mode as the denominator(2.1455 - 3)is negative.

Comment: You're using the formula incorrectly.  Even the Wikipedia article on the Dirichlet distribution is clear that the mode formula applies only when all parameters equal or exceed $1$.

Comment: Yes, what you point out is correct. But I have alpha1=1.266, alpha 2 = 0.386, and alpha 3 = 0.4935 for var1, by using the method of moments. and then alpha 1 + alpha 2 + alpha 3 = 2.1455. Then I get mode of var1 as negative and the modes of other two variables as positive as the ' -' sign in denominator and numerator cancels out. But they sums to 1. I also found mean for each variable but they do not create such problems and they also sums to 1. But what we should do in the cases where alphas are less than 1 and summation of alphas are less than K  (in this case K=3) to find mode?